# typing cursor disappears out of the blue when I use replaceSelectedText("+")

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Does anybody knows whats the problem? when I use this function

```
Object(root).search_txt.txt.replaceSelectedText("+");
```

cursor disappears

Any Idea?

Comment: What does "my cursor disappears" means exactly? Does it completly disappear?

Comment: completely and even when I click it by mouse its still hidden

Answer (score 0):

Is your textField `selectable` in your panel `Properties`?